# Filtering photos in facebook using graph api does not work

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook, android-authenticator

The route `me/home?filter=app_2305272732` should work for photos but when I try that, I am getting active access token required error, but if I just hit me/home then it works perfectly.

Also, I tried `me/home?filter=app_2305272732` in graph api explorer and works there.

So, what am I missing any permission here or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you **clear** all the permission on your graph api explorer(**Get access token** button), you should able see you're missing the **read_stream** permission

> {   "error": {
>       "message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 200   } }

[image]

Comment: No, I have already added read_stream permission. Even though that this permission issue then even "me/home" should not work but it does work.

Comment: Can you try to copy the access token (granted from your app) and paste into access token field on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome%3Ffilter%3Dapp_2305272732 ? Then try to submit it.

Comment: Also, make sure you can see the read_stream permission(inside Scopes field) by paste the access token to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: using the access token got from application and putting them in both the links you mentioned works as desired. read_stream permission is also there.